# How to configure and receiveAndConvert jSON payload into domain Object in Spring Boot and RabbitMQ

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-boot, spring-amqp

Recently I have been having a keen interest on Microservice Architecture using Spring Boot. My implementation has two Spring boot applications;

**Application One** receives requests from a RESTful API, converts and sends jSON payload to a **RabbitMQ queueA**.

**Application Two**, has subscribed to **queueA**, receives the jSON payload(Domain Object User) and is supposed to activate a service within Application Two eg. send email to a user.

Using no XML in my **Application Two** configuration, how do I configure a converter that will convert the jSON payload received from RabbitMQ into a Domain Object User.

Below are snippets from Spring Boot configurations on Application Two

**Application.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRabbit
public class ApplicationInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {

    final static String queueName = "user-registration";

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Autowired
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange topicExchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("user-registrations");
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        return container;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationInitializer.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Waiting for messages...");
    }

}
```

**TestService.java**

```
@Component
public class TestService {

    /**
     * This test verifies whether this consumer receives message off the user-registration queue
     */
    @RabbitListener(queues = "user-registration")
    public void testReceiveNewUserNotificationMessage(User user) {
        // do something like, convert payload to domain object user and send email to this user
    }

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and after some research and testing I learned, that there is more than one way to configure your RabbitMQ-Receiver in SpringBoot, but it is important to choose one and stick with that.

If you decide to go with the [Annotation Driven Listener Endpoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven), what I derive from your usage of @EnableRabbit and @RabbitListener, than the configuration you posted didn´t work for me. What worked is the following:

Derive your Configuration Class from org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListenerConfigurer and override the Method configureRabbitListeners as follows:

```
 @Override
public void configureRabbitListeners(
        RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
    registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(myHandlerMethodFactory());
}
```

and add a MessageHandlerFactory:

```
@Bean
public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory myHandlerMethodFactory() {
    DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
    factory.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());
    return factory;
}
```

Additionally you need to define SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory (as you already did) and Autowire the corresponding ConnectionFactory:

```
@Autowired
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Bean
public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory() {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3);
    factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(10);
    return factory;
}
```

Finishing your Configuration, you need to define the Bean, which handles your Messages and inherits the @RabbitListerner-Annotations. For me I named that EventResultHandler (you named it TestService):

```
    @Bean
public EventResultHandler eventResultHandler() {
    return new EventResultHandler();
}
```

Then in your EventResultHandler (or TestService) you define the @RabbitListener-Methods with their corresponding Queues and the Payload (= the POJO, where your  JSON-Message is serialized to):

```
@Component
public class EventResultHandler {

    @RabbitListener(queues=Queues.QUEUE_NAME_PRESENTATION_SERVICE)
    public void handleMessage(@Payload Event event) {
        System.out.println("Event received");
        System.out.println("EventType: " + event.getType().getText());
    }
}
```

I ommited the needed definition and binding of Queues and Exchanges - you can do that either in one or in another Microservice - or in RabbitMQ-Server manually... But you for sure have to do that.

Comment: You sir.....deserve a medal. For some funny reason after updating my project parent to Spring Boot to 1.3.0.RELEASE few days ago my previous implementation broke. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Create a jackson message converter and set it with `MessageListenerAdapter#setMessageConverter`

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}
```

Where do come from `MessageListenerAdapter` ?

Comment: Make sure that you are importing the right class in order to get this to work - you need a org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter and not a org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter

Answer (score 0):

As per Spring Boot version 2.1.4.RELEASE, you could do the following:

1. Declare "decorated" RabbitMq template with Jackson message converter:

```
    @Bean
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
            rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
           return rabbitTemplate
        }
```

2. Read message from the queue:

```
        var receievedValie = rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert("TestQueue", new ParameterizedTypeReference<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Type getType() {
                return super.getType();
            }
        })
```